# Command line arguments to self-extracting-and-run msi/msp created by IExpress.exe

Tags: windows-installer, iexpress, msp

I have a msp file (an update). It needs to be executed with /qb option (because of some services it installs). I thought IExpress.exe will create a self-extracting-and-run exe of this msp *and* I would be able to pass the /qb argument for run.

I tried to set the argument in step "Install program to launch" as

```
msiexec /qb /update
```

But this gives an error "bad parameter".

Is there a way to pass arguments at "msp-run" time using IExpress.exe?

Comment: i've been looking for a solution for this for days, and then decided to write my own self extractor.

Comment: @MarianTheisen Looks like that's where this is headed. Would have liked to avoid the where-to-extract & delete-after-install coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually pass the name of the MSP file like:

```
msiexec /qb /p foo.msp
```

Answer (score 0):

/qb (basic ui) and /qn (no ui) are silent installations for MSI (meaning the UI sequence is not processed).  There are special considerations for silent installs.

See:

[Applying Patches](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpPatchApply.htm)

> **Applying Patches in Silent Mode**
>
> There are two ways you can apply a patch in silent mode: either launch
>   MsiExec.exe with the /qn command-line parameter, or pass /s to
>   Update.exe.
>
> There is an important consideration to bear in mind when applying a
>   patch in silent mode. In order to operate correctly, the Windows
>   Installer property REINSTALL must be set to ALL and REINSTALLMODE to
>   omus whenever you apply a patch. Since Update.exe always sets these
>   properties at the command line, you do not have to do anything extra
>   if your patch package is applied with Update.exe.
>
> When a patch package is applied with a full user interface, one of
>   your installation’s default dialogs, PatchWelcome, is displayed. It
>   includes control events to set REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE with the
>   correct options. However, since this dialog is not displayed when the
>   end-user interface is suppressed, you must set the properties at the
>   command line, as demonstrated below:
>
> msiexec /p 'path to .msp file' /qn REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=omus
>
> Because a patch does not modify the existing cached .msi database,
>   including the v setting for REINSTALLMODE is unnecessary.

FWIW,  instead of using IExpress or writing your own extractor you could look at Windows Installer XML's Burn bootstrapper engine. It has an [MspPackage Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msppackage.html) that allows you to abstract all of this away and let Burn handle it for you.